# Finding the best use of base ingredients

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Assuming I have a list of recipes, and a limited quantities for a list of ingredients.
What will be the name of a computer algorithm that can find the best use of all the ingredients?

Comment: Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming  But as already mentioned by @OliverDain, the first thing you need to do is create the objective function, which takes a possible solution, and returns a scalar value that indicates the quality of that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define "best use" a little more clearly. e.g. is it "better" to make 4 different things or better to make a lot of 1 thing? Is it better to make one big thing and have no ingredients left over or better to make lots of different things but have a little left over? Are some ingredients more valuable than others so better or worse to have left over?

In any event, this is more of an optimization problem than an ML problem. It's also probably not differentiable so gradient methods are probably out. So you're probably looking at algorithms like [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), or just some [hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).

Basically you'll need to assign a "cost" or a "benefit" to any set of recipes used and ingredients left over. So you need a function that can take in those things and return a score - how good or bad it is. Then you'd "explore the solution space" by choosing recipes, computing what's left over, etc. and score it. Then try again to see if you can get a better score, etc. The algorithms mentioned above are all ways to efficiently explore the set of possible solutions in hopes of getting near-optimal answer.